# Add space between the last item and the end of the list box

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a list box that will hold several hundred items. When the user adds a new item, it will be at the bottom of the list and they will be editing it.

Is there any way to add some white space between the last item and the end of the list box, so the user can scroll the last item up?

Just like you can do in the visual studio code editor, you can scroll down past the end of the text to a certain point and move the last line up.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the ItemsPanel to a StackPanel and add a bottom margin to the StackPanel.

```
<ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,50"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: How to do that with `VirtualizingStackPanel`? Bottom `Margin` doesn't do anything...

Comment: ListBox already uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel` so  you don't have to change its `ItemsPanel`. This isn't an elegant answer but I would create a 'DataTemplateSelector` and have a flag in the view model that specifies it is the last item and use a `DataTemplate` that has a bottom margin applied to it.

Comment: This was a severe performance hit for me. When I had several tabs with a listbox with this template, it would take about a second to load between tabs vs. zero time without it. Does this override the VirtualizingStackPanel? Maybe that's what you were trying to say in the comments?

Comment: Yes, this changes it from a VirtualizingStackPanel to a StackPanel. My suggestion above shows how to use add the margin with a DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: Hey @evanb, This adding bottom margin for each item in listbox. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @HimanshuMange Make sure you are setting the ListBox.ItemsPanel and not ListBox.ItemTemplate. Sorry for the late reply.